# Understanding Investigators Studied Combat

Tags: pathfinder-1e

> At 4th level, an investigator can use a move action to study a single enemy that he can see. Upon doing so, he adds 1/2 his investigator level as an insight bonus on melee attack rolls and as a bonus on damage rolls against the creature. This effect lasts for a number of rounds equal to his Intelligence modifier (minimum 1) or until he deals damage with a studied strike, whichever comes first.

I am just not getting it. Let us assume I have a Level 4 Investigator with Int 16.

What is the right handling of Studied Conbat?

1. The I invest a move action to get a +2/+2 for the next hit. If I want to hit the target again, using studied strike, I have to invest a move action after I hit him.
2. I have to invest one move action to get 3 rounds of +2/+2 and then I have to invest another move action to get another +2/+2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The damage bonus lasts “until he deals damage with a studied strike” (or goes 3 rounds without doing so), so as soon as you use a studied strike once with it, you lose the bonus and must study again to receive the bonus on further attacks.

If you *don’t* use the studied strike feature, and then use another move action to study within those 3 rounds, you get the bonus again—but it doesn’t stack. So the next time you attack, you have two overlapping sets of +2/+2, and only get to apply one of them to any given attack. There is no way to keep studying to pump the bonus larger. You also can’t create a stockpile of them: as soon as you use a studied strike, all of your studied combat bonuses go away. No studying several times, and then making a whole bunch of studied strikes in a row.

The only reason to study again when you have already studied and have the bonus waiting is in order to reset the duration (really, to get a second instance of the bonus that has a fresh 3-round duration).

Comment: The only benefit of using the ability again is resetting the duration.

Comment: @ShadowKras Good point, will mention that.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Eh, I figured that was covered by “have the bonus waiting”—you *don’t* have the bonus waiting (for that target).

Answer (score 8):

Your second option is closest, but not quite accurate because there are two abilities involved. **Studied *Combat*** gives you +2/+2 for up to 3 rounds, and you can enjoy that on all your attacks. It ends after 3 rounds, or if you used (the separate Investigator ability) **Studied *Strike***. Note that Studied Strike is only an option while Studied Combat is active.

You can invest another move action to get another +2/+2 at any time, but due to stacking rules this is only useful to reset the 3 round duration, or to start a fresh 3 rounds of +2/+2 benefits.

Comment: Studied Strike is a completely different EX (then studied combat) this is what I just realized. I guess I have 3 rounds of +2/+2 or until I use the +1d6 studied strike, then it is expiered and I have to invest another move action.

Comment: @ruedi OOH. Well, that conflation caught me too. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @ruedi There, that should be better. I can easily see why the ability was confusing in the first place. :)